# How to assign a typed function to a generic function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am not sure if i framed the question right, basically i just want to enforce the compare function to take 2 args and i want them both to be of same type(T) and the function should return a boolean.

How can achieve something like this .
I couldn't get it working, the below implementation gives the following error :

> Argument of type '(a: CustomType, b: CustomType) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: T, b: T) => boolean'.
> Types of parameters 'a' and 'a' are incompatible.
> Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'CustomType'

```js
function DefaultCompare<T>(a: T, b: T): boolean {
  return a > b;
}

class ClassA<T> {

    public a :T;
    public b :T;
    private compare : (a :T , b :T) => boolean;

    constructor(a : T, b: T,compare= DefaultCompare) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.compare = compare;
    }
}

interface CustomType {
    cost : number,
    name : string,
}
function CustomCompare (a: CustomType, b: CustomType): boolean {
  return a.cost > b.cost;
}


const objA_1 = new ClassA<Number>(1, 2);


const _a : CustomType = { cost : 1, name : 'js'}, 
        _b : CustomType = {cost : 2, name : 'ts'};

const objA_2 = new ClassA<CustomType>(_a, _b, CustomCompare);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEQKbAIYgDZQMJwC2ADhgE6oA8AKgHwAUGAXItQDSIBGL1AlC5zhxsqDEgDeAKESIKUEGSQZEtLgG5JAX0mSI2DAGcDiPPqMBBGqqnSZiYiE7YYERMqbUNd+4+evOiB5edsRkMABuGFCoiBBEpBSBiIyB1IgcAR68iAC8qoLComAatjJxYAZQZCDQcGQpPBmNGAAmLbko6Fi4BCTkqNlS3t5QABYwBgB0yjluwcOIYxOTAbOc88NLU3F9ibOtLRva2pIwYNFkmBAxeCCVRNQAnsQxQ3ZxlUlgIIScqGRsUqIMAYQgxFiVMJgADmgO0oEgsAQJjuUCIvQSMUYLFu90ITxeTRReIJAwEQhEYkQbzkCiUkw+UBUXAZcEqGhOugQnzgnAAVuYAPoARg6YFQAHcTGYDJYAHI-P5kBjCjgAJl4JS5FSZgvcxLR+OeMVm4libKZLFVwNB4MQAHI+QZ7ZoOEDvILMgaHsaOuJGUk1RwQWCkvaoM7NCVyjz+UK1WLJdLDLLKLjDaSGHqOJ6OOn0fF+prJEA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a type for your comparison function parameter:

```
type CompareFn<T> = (a: T, b: T) => boolean;
```

...and then use it in the `compare` parameter of the constructor:

```typescript
constructor(a : T, b: T, compare: CompareFn<T> = DefaultCompare) {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzAQwE4QGIDsA8AVAPigF4oAKZALijwBooAjavAShKIbjgBsJksA3ACghAMwCuWAMbAAlnCxQAIhFHJx3YPCRoI+AhWb0mNFtU48+igN5CoUdMHGpFyKB2EBfEVO7IAzv6wfoEAgvpQtnb2UGDiDNyyUlBulHjCMbHxickMUGkZMWCosgBuyMDQUogo6PnkqXhQxvms7IxcvPzC0fbVWP7AqOIycKgU9XSMRlDVOujU2rWYuIQkyqrqmku6bLaZmcAAFrL+AHRupMiFB1DHp2d5pAw3B-fnc8vrn7qv3t5CWRYSqoNRSaAwcSDRB4cDQfYxaqDepYcQIBgQVC0XpQLDIBDQaiDEpYADm2O8EmkcgUsChwEQOzqhjp0IQsMgxkW9JhcLMHUs-Ei0UczlcZyRwHcjAlcEGXhEQn6yLgDAAVqEAPoARnWWAgAHdggF-OEAHJojGoAza+gAJhYPSVCmRmtSrIZ7Lh62sszlUuottx+MJUAA5Gr-GHPPQcZlNXluWyOdBSNZJfU7fQ8QT6mHgFHPD1lVLVRrNXa9YbjWEcJDk3CDG76An6PXPUyII6hEA)